# How to filter array key by another array number key

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, filter, key

I have 2 array, first array structure is:

```
items: [
    {
      name: "a",
      items: [
         { name: "jack" },
         { name: "jose" },
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "b",
      items: [
         { name: "lara" },
         { name: "jo" },
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "c",
      items: [
         { name: "andy" },
         { name: "hary" },
      ]
    }
]
```

and the second array:

```
number: [
  0: [0, 1],
  1: [1],
  2: [0]
]
```

How to filter "items" by "number" and How can such an output be obtained? (the best solution)

```
{["jack", "jole"],["jo"],["andy"]}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+filter+array+by+other+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: The number array is invalid. is it supposed to be an Object?

Comment: @FarhadKhan Yes، it is supposed to be an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few maps would do it:

the output you wish is not valid JS so I made a nested array

```js
const arr1 = [{ name: "a", items: [{ name: "jack" }, { name: "jose" }, ] }, { name: "b", items: [{ name: "lara" }, { name: "jo" }, ] }, { name: "c", items: [{ name: "andy" }, { name: "hary" }, ] } ], numbers = [ [0, 1], [1], [0] ]; 

const res = numbers
  .map((arr, i) => arr
    .map(key => arr1[i].items[key].name)
  )
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your number variable has to be an Object.

```js
let items = [
  {
    name: "a",
    items: [{ name: "jack" }, { name: "jose" }]
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    items: [{ name: "lara" }, { name: "jo" }]
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    items: [{ name: "andy" }, { name: "hary" }]
  }
];

let number = {
  0: [0, 1],
  1: [1],
  2: [0]
};

let result = []
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(number)){
  let names = []
  value.forEach(value => {
    names.push(items[key].items[value].name)
  })
  result.push(names)
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Still an array `[]` and not an object `{}`